# Create extra user Marketing Cloud FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp, sftp

Is it possible to add an extra FTP user to your Marketing Cloud instance? I can't find this option within administration. We want to have multiple users due to security reasons.

Best regards,

Klaas

Answer (score 3):

Not by any standard means, as even the [documentation on SFTP](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_ftp_accounts.htm&type=5) states the following:

> Marketing Cloud allows one FTP user per MID.

Just in case you can check in with your SFMC Account Executive about this requirement, I wouldn't be surprised if they actually are able to create additional FTP accounts.

EDIT: Seems to be possible now, as detailed by Lukas.

Comment: Yes, they previously offered multiple users, but no longer. It is a single ftp user per BU

Comment: It is a full time job, updating old answers to accommodate for all the releases :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Essential update - March 2020**
It is now possible to create additional (up to 3 per BU) users in the user interface. Follow these steps:

1. Hover over your name in the app switcher and click **Setup**.
2. Click **Data Management**.
3. Click **FTP Accounts**.
4. Click **Add FTP User**. By default, the username is the MID number for
   your current Marketing Cloud MID, including the current parent
   account or child business unit.
5. Enter an email address for the new FTP user.
6. Enter an initial password for the user. Password complexity
   requirements combine Marketing Cloud password policy and server-side
   FTP password requirements. These policies require a minimum of 12
   characters and no reuse of the most recent password.
7. Reenter the initial password for the user.
8. Select **Read Only** or **Full** for User Permissions.
9. To restrict account access to specific IP addresses, enter each
   address in the **Whitelist IPs** field and click **Add**.
10. Save your changes. By default, this process creates an enabled,
     active user as unlocked with a valid current password.

Release note: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2020_platform_ftp_users.htm&type=5

User guide: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_add_ftp_accounts.htm&type=5

---

**Original post:**

There is indeed a single FTP user / BU limit, where MID is your user name. However you can still use an external SFTP as a file location, allowing multiple folders/accounts to be added to a single BU. You can do so, by following [this guide.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_create_file_transfer_location.htm&type=5)

You need to observe that file drop triggered automations don't support external SFTP locations, but require the file to be dropped on the Enhanced FTP. This is the single key drawback of this workaround.

Comment: This is a good workaround solution - what I do to get around the drawback is that when I drop a file to the external FTP, I then have the 3rd party program drop an empty file to the SFMC FTP to trigger the automation to run the import, etc. from the external one.